# Не могу вывести минимум и максимум в label

Tags: visual-basic

Что здесь не так, подчёркивает label4 и пишет «Ошибка компиляции»: неправильное число параметров или недопустимые значения свойства

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Min = Round(Min, 2): Max = Round(Max, 2)
    Load Label4(i)
    Label4(i).Visible = True
    Label4(i).Top = Label4(0).Top + Label4(0).Height + 20
    Label4(i).Caption = Str(Min)
    Load Label5(i)
    Label5(i).Visible = True
    Label5(i).Top = Label5(0).Top + Label5(0).Height + 20
    Label5(i).Caption = Str(Min)    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Надо не `Label4.Caption` а `Label4.Text`. То же само в Label5 надо.

Comment: @Концевой Игорь Николаевич если мой ответ Вам помог пометьте его как ответ, пожалуйста.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)